# what means "stock images only" in google Custom Search JSON API

Tags: google-image-search

In the documentation for the [Google Custom Search JSON API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/ImgType?hl=en), there is a parameter mentioned called imageType, which includes multiple values: ["clipart", "face", "lineart", "stock", "photo", "animated"]. I am having difficulty understanding the meaning of "stock" among them. The official documentation does not provide an explanation for it.

I attempted to inquire with ChatGPT, and the response I received was that 'stock' refers to stock photos, which are typically high-quality, professionally taken photographs used for advertising, publishing, and other commercial purposes. Is this information correct?